# Definition of real exponent

Tags: reference-request, exponential-function, definition

Is there some article or chapter in some book which covers proving all usual properties of exponential function with definition of real exponentiation via showing that sequence $\{a^{x_n}\}$ converges when sequence $\{x_n\}$ of rationals converges and the value of the limit of $\{a^{x_n}\}$ is independent of the sequence $\{x_n\}$, where $a>0$ ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in Terence Tao's book "Analysis I". See section 6.7, p152, third edition. Lemma 6.7.1 captures the essence of your question.

Comment: Out of interest: How does he define $a^x$ in the first place for rational $x$, but probably irrational $a$?

Comment: Assume $x$ is positive. First, $x^n$ for naturals in the obvious way: repeated multiplication. Then $x^n$ for integers by $x^{-n} = 1/x^n$ where $n$ is again a positive natural number. Then $x^{1/n}$ as the unique root of the equation $a^n = x$. Then $x^{p/q}$ by $(x^{1/q})^p$ and eventually for reals by considering limits as in the OP's question.

Comment: At each step, some work has to be done. For example, showing that such equations have unique roots takes some work and showing that $x^{p/q}$ makes sense takes work as well.

Comment: In my honest opinion, it is better to develop some real analysis first and leave exponentiation undefined until one has treaten (power) series and continuïty. Then the existence of roots will follow by intermediate value theorem and one can define the exponential using power series in a much cleaner way. But it may obscure a little bit what's going on.

Comment: thanks for your expansive reply. I agree that probably the most elegant way is to develop some analysis first. Actually, the most convincing definition I find is to define $\ln x := \int_1 ^x \frac{1}{t}dt $ for positive $x$, then some properties are immediate, such as monotone increase, or product to sum rule, etc (via integration by sub/parts…) Then exponential $e^x$ is defined as its inverse function. Now, any $a^b$ is defined to be $e^{b \ln a}$, where $a >0 $.

Comment: The definition of $e^x$ via its series expansion, well, I personally will prefer to work with the integral rather. But that is up to one's taste!

Comment: Yes, the integral approach works fine. It's indeed a matter of taste. I prefer the series method as it also quickly yields cosine and sine (which is also possible using integrals, for example via $\arctan(x)$, but there one has to be a little more careful with the domains/codomains of the functions involved).